# Returning the order number of sub-string in a text

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to parse the string and I am having trouble identifying the order number.

Here few examples with expected answer. I need Oracle SQL expression to ruturn the value

```
SOURCE_COLUMN      PARAMETER         RETURN_VALUE
AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD    AAA               1
AAA_BBB_CCCC_DDD   BBB               2
AAA_BBB_CC_DDD     CC                3
AAA_BBBB_CCC_DDD   DDD               4
AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD    EEE               0
```

Here is SQL to generate first two columns

```
select 'AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD' SOURCE_COLUMN, 'AAA' PARAM FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 'AAA_BBB_CCCC_DDD' SOURCE_COLUMN, 'BBB' PARAM FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 'AAA_BBB_CC_DDD' SOURCE_COLUMN, 'CC' PARAM FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 'AAA_BBBB_CCC_DDD' SOURCE_COLUMN, 'DDD' PARAM FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 'AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD' SOURCE_COLUMN, 'EEE' PARAM FROM DUAL
```

Comment: You need to clarify your question a bit more, not sure what you are trying to achieve here. If you just want to select a column using SQL, this is trivial and should not be asked here since it takes about 2 seconds to find it out on google. Elaborate please.

Comment: I see. I have a values that are "_" separated and stored in one column. Based on the second column "PARAM". I need to identify the position of that PARAM in the search string. I cannot use INSTR because it returns the position in the string whereas I need to return order number. I do not wont to write separate function to loop through the string right now, but I may if that is the only option. I thought somebody can suggest a regular expression for example

Comment: What do you mean by "the position" of the PARAM? Is that 1 for AAA, 2 for BBB, 3 for CCC, etc.? Or did i get it wrong?

Comment: Yes Lawrence. That is correct for the example provided above. in this example however 'AAA_CCC_BBB_DDD' CCC is in second position

Comment: Isn't that allways the result of INSTR divided by 4?
For BBB you would get 6, which divided (with integer division) by 4 will yield 1. This is your position, if you consider that the first one is zero.

Comment: no the length of the param is not always the same.

Comment: Ah, i see. Your example made it look like it was. Add this note to the question.

Comment: Well, you could try to create a regex for this, but it will not be pretty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query does what you want:

```
select (case when source_column like '%'||param||'%'
             then 1 +
                  coalesce(length(substr(source_column, 1, instr(source_column, param) - 1)) -
                           length(replace(substr(source_column, 1, instr(source_column, param) - 1), '_', '')),
                           0)
              else 0
        end) as pos
from t;
```

The idea is much simpler than the query looks.  It finds the matching parameter and then takes the initial substring up to that point.  You can count the number of `'_'` by using a trick:  take the length of the string and then subtract the length of the string when you replace the `'_'` with `''`.  The value you want is actually one more than this value.  And, if the pattern is not found, then return `0`.

Answer (score 0):

For your particular example (stable string patterns):

```
SQL> with t as (
  2  select 'AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD' SOURCE_COLUMN, 'AAA' PARAM FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  select 'AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD' SOURCE_COLUMN, 'BBB' PARAM FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4  select 'AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD' SOURCE_COLUMN, 'CCC' PARAM FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5  select 'AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD' SOURCE_COLUMN, 'DDD' PARAM FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  6  select 'AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD' SOURCE_COLUMN, 'EEE' PARAM FROM DUAL
  7  )
  8  select SOURCE_COLUMN, PARAM, floor((instr(SOURCE_COLUMN,param)+3)/4) p  from t;

SOURCE_COLUMN   PAR          P                                                  
--------------- --- ----------                                                  
AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD AAA          1                                                  
AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD BBB          2                                                  
AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD CCC          3                                                  
AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD DDD          4                                                  
AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD EEE          0
```

Comment: As we already discussed in the comments of the question, the size of the param is not always 3, it is variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` in the following manner

```
SELECT source_column
        ,PARAM
        ,CASE WHEN ind IS NULL THEN 0 
         ELSE Row_number() over ( PARTITION BY source_column ORDER BY ind) END AS Return_Value 
FROM   (SELECT source_column
                ,Param
                ,CASE WHEN Instr(source_column, param) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE Instr(source_column, param) END AS Ind 
        FROM   (select 'AAA_BBB_CC_DDD' SOURCE_COLUMN, 'AAA' Param FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                select 'AAA_BBB_CC_DDD' SOURCE_COLUMN, 'BBB' Param FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                select 'AAA_BBB_CC_DDD' SOURCE_COLUMN, 'CC' Param FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                select 'AAA_BBB_CC_DDD' SOURCE_COLUMN, 'DDD' Param FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                select 'AAA_BBB_CC_DDD' SOURCE_COLUMN, 'EEE' Param FROM DUAL
                )
        )
```

here SQL Fiddle to show results http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/26754